# How did the first T-1000 die?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In Terminator Genisys, Skynet sends a terminator (a T-1000) to 1973 in order to kill Sarah. It is able to kill her parents, but Sarah swims away and runs into a T-800 that was sent back *to help her*. We see Sarah in the water, under a small wooden bridge, looking up at the T-800. Then we see the T-800 carrying Sarah away to safety.

We never see the T-1000 nor do we find out how it was killed. They are extraordinarily difficult to kill (in 1984 Sarah and the T-800 are able to dispatch one after A LOT of planning and a lot of acid).  How did the 1973 T-1000 get destroyed?

Comment: iirc they are supposed to go to sleep or self destruct after their mission is complete. To avoid doing anything that may prevent the rise of skynet.

Comment: The T-1000's mission wasn't complete though: Sarah was still alive.

Comment: Terminator: I have to stay functional until my mission is complete. Then it doesn't matter. Terminator 2: Judgment Day

Comment: If the mission was kill Sarah and not kill her parents. Or if it thought that she was dead.

Comment: The T-1000's mission wasn't complete (Sarah lived).

Comment: It may have seen Sarah jump into the water and made the judgement that she drowned therefore completing his mission. Terminators can be wrong in their calculations.

Comment: Maybe?  I mean that doesn't seem strongly supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We never see the T-1000 nor do we find out how it was killed. They are extraordinarily difficult to kill (in 1984 Sarah and the T-800 are able to dispatch one after A LOT of planning and a lot of acid).

While it's not explicit, it's almost certainly the same Terminator.

T-1000s are difficult to Terminate, so it will survive until 1984.

If it failed to kill Sarah in 1973 and the T-800 Guardian was able to use its expertise to incapacitate it and successfully hide from it for 11 years and the T-1000 knows that Kyle Reece is sent back to 1984 and knows he's John Connor's father, he'll infer that Sarah Connor is likely to contact him on arrival, so that's the T-1000's best chance to reacquire and terminate Sarah.